# Winium is unable to find JavaFX element

Tags: selenium, javafx, winium

I use `UISpy` to identify elements of a Windows desktop application. I use AutomationId of element as follows:

```
WiniumDriver driver = new WiniumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9999"), option);
driver.findElement(By.id("JavaFX98")).click();
```

I got exception during execution, I tried to identify same element also by name:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
Element cannot be found (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 30.45 seconds
```

Comment: What makes you think that winium supports javafx? I don't see it listed here as a supported platform: https://github.com/2gis/Winium

Answer (score 1):

Same issue facing In my project. Please use this dependency.
com.github.2gis.winium
winium-webdriver
0.1.0-1